# Set "of:" property to previous element in jQuery ui position plugin

Tags: jquery, user-interface, position, css-position

Im using jQuery ui position plugin to set some helping boxes next to their previous elements, it works if I set the previous box id, but doesnt if I try to make it more dynamic and, for this, I need it to be dynamic. Lets see the code:

CSS

```
.helpBox {
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;        
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #bcd5e6;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInformation" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" CssClass="required" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
<div class="helpBox">This is a helping box.</div>
```

Sorry for the asp.net code, its just a textbox.

JS

```
$(".helpBox").position({
    of: $("#txtInformation"),
    my: "left center",
    at: "right center",
    offset: "10 0"
});
```

And that works, but if I try to use this so I can reuse it and make it work with all the help boxes it doesn't:

```
$(".helpBox").position({
    of: $(this).prev(),
    my: "left center",
    at: "right center",
    offset: "10 0"
});
```

Now I wonder how to make it work. That property is supposed to handle that but somehow it isn't. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing an object to the `.position` function. The object is being defined before it is passed to the function, so `$(this).prev()` will be evaluated in the context of the code that calls the method. `this` will *not*, necessarily, refer to your `.helpBox` here.

However, if you iterated over your help boxes with `$.each`, then `this` at each iteration would refer to the actual box:

```
$('.helpBox').each(function() {
   $(this).position({
     of: $(this).prev(),
     my: "left center",
     at: "right center",
     offset: "10 0"
   });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9NmTw/)

Comment: I was just trying to do something like this but inside the property. Anyway, it doesn't work for me, does it work for you?

Comment: Ah, sorry, `position` is a jQuery UI function and not a part of the standard jQuery library, so it doesn't behave exactly as I expected it to, and it seems you can't perform set-based operations like that. You'll have to iterate over the collection, see my update.